# Determining the continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, continuity

How do I determine if a function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$? I am able to solve questions where continuity on a particular point is asked to be found, but not ones involving the $\mathbb{R}$.

Question. Is the function $f$, defined by

\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^{2} & \text{if} \ x\leq 1\\\\
x & \text{if} \ x > 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Here you need to prove continuity only at $x=1$ as the two pieces are continuous on the respective intervals

Comment: A function $f$ is said to be continuous on $\mathbb R$ if it is continuous at each point of $\mathbb R$. So take $a\in\mathbb R$ show that $f$ is continuous at $a$. Since $a$ was chosen arbitrary $f$ is continuous at each point of $\mathbb R$ hence it is continuous on $\mathbb R$